# Get Oracle DB status from .net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, oracle

I have several hundred DB's on our network, mostly MSSQL that are in SCOM. We have a few Oracle DB's that are not and will never be in SCOM. The catch here is that I do not have access nor will I ever be given access to these DB's. I only have access to Oracle Enterprise Manager.

I am tasked with providing status of these Oracle DB's as a basic Up/Down in a dashboard. Basically I need db.name,db.status and that is it.

For the life of me I cannot find a way to get this information into something I can parse.

So far these are the things I have tried.
1.Oracle OEM Api(Documentation on this was rough for me, this could be the ticket but I am at a loss on what method I need to use)
2.Scraping the OEM portal for the table of DB statuses(Get javascript errors with WebRequest and login errors with WebBrowser)

I feel this has to be easy and I am missing something. As I am not an Oracle admin or even user I am at a loss.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You already have the database name, then once easy approach is to try and connect to your database. If connection successful then it's *UP* else *DOWN*. Something like

```
string dbStatus = string.Empty;
try
{
  //Connecting to DB;
  dbStatus = "Up";
}
catch
{
dbStatus = "Down";
//log the exception
}
```

Comment: I will update my question to mention I do not have access to the DB's directly